# How to make any sprite dissapear in c++/sfml 2.1?

Tags: c++, events, sprite, sfml

I am a beginner and developing a game in c++/sfml. I don't know how I can make any shape or sprite disappear on any specific condition?
For Example:-

```
if(A-KEY-IS-PRESSED)
{
    sprite.disappear
}
```

I think now everyone can understand what I'm talking about. How can I do it in sfml/c++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, you have a `RenderWindow`, lets call it `win`. And you are doing something like this:

```
win.draw(sprite);
```

To make the sprite disappear, simply don't do that.

```
if(A-KEY-IS-PRESSED)
    sprite_is_visible = false;
...

if (sprite_is_visible)
    win.draw(sprite);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good solution for you, if you already know how to create a sprite (from a list).

If not, then simply tell me and I will give you a fully working code example.

Code for removal of Sprites:

```
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
                {
                    sf::Vector2f mousecoords(mMainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y)));
                    EnemyList.remove_if([=](sf::Sprite newSprite){return newSprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(mousecoords); });
                }
```